# Gestor biblioteca en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un gestor de biblioteca y no me da los resultados esperados.
Al introducir los libros so lo se guarda uno.
En mostrar los libros prestados me los muestra todos.
Deberia Mostrar lo siguiente:

0         1      2          3       4       5
0      llibre1   llibre2   llibre3 llibre4   null
1       autor1  autor2   autor3     autor4   null
2        si       no       no         si     null

Metodos

```
     public static void añadirlibro(String[][] b) {
        String titulo, autor,prestado="no";


         System.out.println("\nEscribe el titulo: ");
         titulo = lector.next();
         System.out.println("\nEscribe el autor: ");
         autor = lector.next();

         for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){

            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++){
                  b[0][j]= titulo;
                  b[1][j]= autor;
                  b[2][j]= prestado;
        }
    }




    }


    }
       public static void mostrarlibrosprestados(String[][] a){
        String prestado= "si";

        if (prestado.equals("si")) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");

            }         
        }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Menu main

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String[][] biblio= new String[10][10];

       String  libros =" ",prest= " "   ;

        boolean salir = true;
        int opcion; 

        while (salir) {

            System.out.println("Menu:\n"
                    + "1.Dar de Alta un Libro\n"
                    + "2.Prestar Libro\n"
                    + "3.Mostrar Libros prestados\n"
                    + "4.Mostrar Libros completos\n"
                    + "5.Salir\n");
            System.out.println("Escoger opcion ");

            opcion = lector.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {

                case 1:
                  Metodos.añadirlibro(biblio);

                    break;

                case 2:
                    Metodos.prestarlibro(biblio);
                    break;

                case 3:
                   Metodos.mostrarlibrosprestados(biblio);

                    break;

                case 4:
                    Metodos.mostrarlibros(biblio);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    salir = false;
                    break;

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola. Un consejo que te doy totalmente gratuito. No pongas nunca o intenta evitarlos al máximo nombres a los métodos o funciones, variables, constantes y clases con caracteres especiales tipo: ñ, vocales acentuadas, etc. ya que aunque esta permitido te van a dar muchísimos problemas.

Comment: Otra cosa, haces referencia a "Metodos.añadirlibro(bibilio);" pero ese ¿Metodos de donde lo sacas? Estoy intentando mirarte el fallo pero es que tienes una ensalada de código que da gusto, aun no es código espagueti pero dale tiempo que crezca y verás.

Comment: Hola buenas. Metodos.añadirlibro(bibilio); esta en otro fichero llamado Metodos y lo llamo con eso. Y lo siento por tenerlo el codigo asi simplemnte me daba un error en la pregunta y la tuve que editar soy rookie preguntando.

Comment: El programa tiene un menu donde llamas a otro fichero llamado Metodos y en el fichero metodos tiene que estar el codigo donde tienes que dar de alta un libro, prestar un libro , mostrar todos los libros y mostrar solo los libros prestados.

Comment: Ok...entonces has creado una Clase que has llamado Metodos, está bien pensado pero aun te falta una vuelta mas para nombrar esa clase correctamente, pista para el nombre: ¿a quien se le aplican esos metodos?

Comment: Se aplican en una array creado en el main llamado biblio.      Este seria el array:                                                     
String[][] biblio= new String[10][10];

Comment: No....a ver....me refiero....los metodos que has creado en esa clase "Metodos" hacen cosas y modifican una entidad de tu programa, a que entidad es la que ¿afectan dichos cambios? Antes de crear cualquier programa necesitas análisis y planificación. Y lo primero de todo investigar las entidades que entran en juego y que necesitas crear.

Comment: Si, En el fichero metodos estan los codigos para añadir libros, cambiar si un libro esta prestado o no y mostrar libros.

Comment: Si...exacto...modifican a libro....pero algo aun no me cuadra....no afectan a nadie mas??? quien seria la otra entidad existente a la que afecta????

Comment: No, en teoria a libro solamente

Comment: Biblioteca???? te olvidaste de ella????  Mira en el siguiente enlace el sencillo diagrama de clases que he hecho rápidamente para orientarnos: https://ibb.co/v3dXLPd

Comment: Biblioteca es una clase y tiene los métodos añadir libro, prestar libro y mostrar libros prestados o todos. Entonces yo crearía de momento dos clases: Libro y Biblioteca y en cada una de ellas pondría sus métodos de cada uno de ellos. Y en la clase principal solamente dejaria los metodos y variables de lo que seria el menu y demas cosas de la interfaz gráfica.

Comment: Es es como lo dice se llaman main y metodos en vez de libros y biblioteca